# The sidebar is not updating on clicking the second time in react js

Tags: reactjs

My requirement is that when I click on a name in the table row, the corresponding details should display in the sidebar. This is working fine in the first attempt, but the requirement is that the click on the next entry should update the sidebar without manually refreshing the page.
Also, I noticed that once the sidebar has opened (on the first attempt), then I am not able to click on any entry in the table until I refresh the page manually.

Please help.

I am using the Sidebar from "react-sidebar"

**Following is App.js**

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import Sidebar1 from "./Sidebar1";
import './App.css'



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { //state is by default an object
      students: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Wasif',
          age: 21,
          email: 'wasif@email.com'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ali',
          age: 19,
          email: 'ali@email.com'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Saad',
          age: 16,
          email: 'saad@email.com'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Asad',
          age: 25,
          email: 'asad@email.com'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'kiwi',
          age: 20,
          email: 'kiwi@email.com'
        }
      ],
      isAboutVisible: false,
      selectedStudent: ''
    }

  }


  handleClick(items) {
    this.setState({
      isAboutVisible: false
    });
    this.state.students.map(student => {
      //const { id, name, age, email } = student;

      if (items === student.id) {

        this.setState({
          isAboutVisible: true,
          selectedStudent: student
        });


      }
      return student;
    });



  }



  renderTableData() {

    return this.state.students.map((student) => {
      const {
        id,
        name
      } = student //destructuring
      return ( <
        tr onClick = {
          () => {
            this.handleClick(student.id)
          }
        }
        key = {
          id
        } >


        <
        td > {
          name
        } < /td>

        <
        /tr>
      )
    })
  }




  render() {


    return (


      <
      div >

      <
      h1 id = 'title' > React Dynamic Table < /h1>

      <
      table id = 'students' >
      <
      tbody > {
        this.renderTableData()
      } <
      /tbody> < /
      table >



      {
        this.state.isAboutVisible ? < Sidebar1 abc = {
          this.state.selectedStudent
        }
        handleClose = {
          this.handleClose
        }
        /> : null } < /
        div >

      );
    }
  }






  export default App;
```

***And the following is Sidebar1.***

```js
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";
import './Sidebar1.css'

class Sidebar1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sidebarOpen: true,
    };
    this.onSetSidebarOnpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);

  }


  onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
    this.setState({
      sidebarOpen: open
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
          <div className="help">
              <Sidebar sidebar={<div><p>Name : {this.props.abc.name}</p><p> Age : {this.props.abc.age}</p> <p>Email : {this.props.abc.email}</p></div>   }
          rootClassName="xyz"
                sidebarClassName="imp"      

            open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
            onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
                    pullRight                
                    styles={{ sidebar: { background: "beige",width:300,paddingLeft :5},overlay : {width:0} }}

          >        

          </Sidebar>

          </div> 
        );
  }
}

export default Sidebar1
```

Comment: Hope you have idea about the react sidebar else check this URL:  https://reactjsexample.com/tag/sidebar/

Comment: Please your `Sidebar1` file code as well so that I can figure out the exact cause of this problem...

Comment: @aakritipriya check the edited answer, I just updated...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried optimising your `handleClick` function -:

```
  handleClick(items){   
   this.setState({
     isAboutVisible:true,
     selectedStudent: this.state.students.find(student => items === student.id)
   });
  }
```

Also for sanity we can add this condition so that the `Sidebar1` component gets refreshed every time `selectedStudent` changes in the state.

```
(this.state.selectedStudent && <Sidebar1 abc={this.state.selectedStudent} handleClose={this.handleClose}/>)
```

The root cause is the drawer's width which is obstacle for you, we need to set the style for the `SideBar` component like this-:

```
<Sidebar
          sidebar={
            <div>
              <p>Name : {this.props.abc.name}</p>
              <p> Age : {this.props.abc.age}</p>{" "}
              <p>Email : {this.props.abc.email}</p>
            </div>
          }
          rootClassName="xyz"
          sidebarClassName="imp"
          open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
          onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
          pullRight
          styles={{
            sidebar: {
              background: "beige",
              width: 300,
              paddingLeft: 5,
            },
            overlay: { width: 0 },
            root: { left: "none", width: "60%" },
          }}
        >
</Sidebar>
```

Basically we need to add `root: {left: "none", width: "60%"}` in the `styles`

Comment: The handleClick(items) is working fine.Can you please clarify where are you suggesting to put the sanity check in the code. The first atempt is going fine.Unable to click during second click.Also in addition to that,after the first attempt, I am getting the following warning at                                       
  console.index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Sidebar`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Sidebar (at Sidebar1.js:29)
    in Sidebar1 (at App.js:75)
    in div (at App.js:63)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)

Comment: @aakritipriya finally got the bug, since the drawer takes full width `width: 100%` so the clicks you are doing is registering itself on the drawer component, not on the list items (which will ultimately change the state for new `selectedStudent`)... I have updated the answer above...

Comment: @aakritipriya here is a working demo -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5q4mfo?